# Is Google Chrome Frame Installed and Enabled?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome-frame

How can I detect whether Google Chrome Frame (GCF) is installed and enabled? Any javascript or css type solution is welcome. (Strict no-bloat policy against using other frameworks and downloads.)

I am building a website that uses HTML 5 features, not all of which are supported by Microsoft Internet Explorer < v10 (at least). I have a check (javascript) for MSIE 9 or earlier, but this alone would be bad if GCF is installed. If GCF is installed and enabled, the application should go on its merry way without concern for the fact that it's running in MSIE.

I've been googling and it looks like navigation.plugins() might provide a solution, but then I need more information to check specifically for GCF; so I don't yet know how to use it. As suggested above, I'm not limiting answers to navigation.plugins(). I'm just saying that's as far as I've gotten on my own; so, if you know how to reference this specific plugin, it's a possible solution.

Comment: [Understanding Chrome Frame User Agent](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started/understanding-chrome-frame-user-agent)

Comment: if GCF is installed, you don't want to MSIE9 behaviors, right? since GCF renders with webkit (chrome), shouldn't your JS test return that it's running inside chrome and not inside IE in that case?

Comment: What response would I get if the browser is Firefox of Opera, for example. The problem is specific to MSIE and I was planning to do this test only if the browser is MSIE v9 or lower.

Comment: I think the link provided above by Waleed Khan could hold the answer. I'll have to do a full test, but I can see from first try that "chrome" does not appear (my MSIE 9) with navigator.userAgent and should not appear with the alternative window.externalHost ... it's string checking, but that's quite doable. Was imagining a solution that returns true of false.

Comment: Don't know why someone thought it such a bad question that they had to give it a -1. It's obvious that it's important given MSIE is making it hard for people to get all their HTML 5 upgrades, even when they finally have them. (Must buy Windows 8 for v10 IE ...) V9 MSIE (and below) will remain in use for quite some time.

Comment: BTW: MIT offered some javascript to check to see if particular HTML 5 features are supported; but not for datalist, which is the one I'm concerned about right now. Don't want to install a large javascript file to check for one feature, but it seemed like a lead ... maybe looking under the hood to see how things actually worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to schedule my own tests for later, but at present; it appears I have [confirmation](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started/chrome-frame-faq#TOC-How-do-I-tell-if-a-user-has-Google-Chrome-Frame-installed-) for Waleed Khan's answer in comments below the question. The User Agent will return a string that contains the term "chromeframe." That seems to be spot on for what I need. I only need to check if the browser is MSIE < 10, and I already have a check for that. Should be fast (I presume) and seems to cover all the necessary bases.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look at using [Browser Feature Detection](http://html5doctor.com/using-modernizr-to-detect-html5-features-and-provide-fallbacks/) rather than browser sniffing. This method will allow you to determine if the browser supports the required features of your app, regardless of whether it's IE or not.

You could (or some would argue, should) take this further and simply hide the parts of your app that depend on these features, or provide suitable fallbacks, rather than completely blocking those users.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, Browser Feature Detection would be a good solution and was the first thing I wanted to do. Your suggestion is good and may be the right answer for others, so I'm giving it a bump up. It looks like a lot more processing than I need though and I like fast ... really fast. I don't block anyone from using the site; just block / hide a feature for MSIE (v < 10) and suggest they use something else or install GCF or continue using the site without that feature. I know that it's only MSIE (v < 10) that I need be concerned with and which feature it is. All I need now is to check for GCF.

Comment: If you know what feature it is, you'll find it much more reliable (and probably easier) to detect support for that feature rather than sniffing the user agent. It might add some minor start-up time, but it won't affect the performance once running. Really, I think you've just answered your own question ;o)

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I know which browser doesn't support it and test for that first. If it's a different browser, I don't test at all. If GCF is active, the user agent returns a string that includes the term "chromeframe." That seems pretty reliable. On the other hand, I just don't care about things like Firefox 2 or whatever. Anybody with a browser that old must be used to having nothing work.  On the third hand; feature detection would be much much better for continuing development in the future ... just to be sure and to avoid going through the pains I have to be sure about the details

Answer (score 1):

The way to see if GCF is functioning is by looking at the user agent. If you see 'chromeframe' token in it then it's installed and enabled. Now if some software disables chrome frame BHO then a following script should tell if you it is installed:

```
function IsGCFInstalled() {

      try {

        var i = new ActiveXObject('ChromeTab.ChromeFrame');
        if (i) {
          return true;
        }
      } catch(e) {
        log('ChromeFrame not available, error:', e.message);
        // squelch
      }

      return false;

}
```